# How to get a current Item's info from QtGui.QListWidget?

Tags: python, listview, pyqt, listviewitem

Created a QtGui.QListWidget list widget:

```
myListWidget = QtGui.QListWidget()
```

Populated this ListWidget with QListWidgetItem list items:

```
for word in ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']:
    list_item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(word, myListWidget)
```

Now connect a function on list_item's left click:

```
def print_info():
    print myListWidget.currentItem().text()


myListWidget.currentItemChanged.connect(print_info)
```

As you see from my code all I am getting on a left click is a list_item's label name. But aside from a label name I would like to get a list_item's index number (order number as it is displayed in ListWidget). I would like to get as much info on left-clicked list_item as possible. I looked at dir(my_list_item). But I can't anything useful there ( other than already used my_list_item.text() method which returns a list_item's label name). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [QListWidget.currentRow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#currentRow-prop) to get the index of the current item:

```
def print_info():
    print myListWidget.currentRow()
    print myListWidget.currentItem().text()
```

A [QListWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html) does not know its own index: it's up to the list-widget to manage that.

You should also note that [currentItemChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#currentItemChanged) sends the current and previous items as arguments, so you could simplify to:

```
def print_info(current, previous):
    print myListWidget.currentRow()
    print current.text()
    print current.isSelected()
    ...
```

Comment: How do use with multiple selections?

Comment: @laserpython. [QListWidget.selectedItems](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#selectedItems).

Comment: @ekhumoro I meant how do you get the indices of the selectedItems? selectedItems just returns text values, not indices... there is currentRow() but no currentRows()

Comment: Please read the docs I linked to. The `selectedItems()`method returns a list of items, not text. There can only be one current item, so `currentRows()` makes no sense. To get a `QModelIndex` from an item, use [QListWidget.indexFromItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#indexFromItem).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have listed some of the things you can display about the current item, if you want more than this then you should look through the PyQt Documentation. [link](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html)

```
 def print_info():
    print myListWidget.currentItem().text()
    print myListWidget.row(myListWidget.currentItem())
    print myListWidget.checkState()  # if it is a checkable item
    print myListWidget.currentItem().toolTip().toString()
    print myListWidget.currentItem().whatsThis().toString()

myListWidget.currentItemChanged.connect(print_info)
```